# Flutter save OneSignal notification message

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, onesignal

I want to save the message from OneSignal push notification, so I can create a notification list.. but I have no idea to achieve this.. I open the Onesignal for flutter documentation but still no clue.. anyone can share some references to me?

Answer (score 0):

In your main.dart make sure you have the listener setNotificationReceivedHandler activated. Then just save the notification.payload elements

```
OneSignal.shared.setNotificationReceivedHandler((notification) {
      this.setState(() {
        _debugLabelString =
            "Received notification: \n${notification.jsonRepresentation().replaceAll("\\n", "\n")}";
        newNotificationTitle = notification.payload.title;
        newNotificationBody = notification.payload.body;
      });
    });
```